# Incrementing Dereferenced Iterator

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, increment, dereference

I'm doing c++ primer exercises (3.25), I'm trying to increment a dereferenced iterator. This is my idea:

```
vector <int> arcNotas(10,0);        //hold amount of grades by 10-20-30....90-100
int notas = 0;
auto it = arcNotas.begin();
while (cin >> notas && notas!= 1000) {
    it += notas / 10;                   //move the iterator to the right position
    *it++;                              //increment the quantity of elements in that position
    it = arcNotas.begin();              //reset to the initial position
}
```

But when i compile it, the compiler says (after the first "notes" input) "`vector` iterator not incrementable". I'm dereferencing `it` specifically to do it... i just don't understand what is wrong. I searched but all I found was issues by incrementing `it`, not `*it`.

Comment: Note: `*it++` means `*(it++)`. If you mean `(*it)++` then you must write that :)

Comment: @psmears Another reason to abolish `++`.

Comment: //move the iterator to the right position.. why this is right ?

Comment: Note also, `arcNotas.at(notas / 10)++` takes only one line and looks simpler. Using iterators *everywhere* is a bad idea.

Comment: @Human Helfawi my idea is: if i have a grade 90, then put it in the 9th object of the vector. thats what i mean with that phrase

Comment: @soon the exercise demands iterators

Comment: Try providing a small but complete (i.e. with a  `main()` and able to be compiled and linked) sample of code that exhibits your problem.  Odds are, your code is exhibiting undefined behaviour (`it += notas/10` can easily move the iterator to the end of the vector or beyond, after which it should not be dereferenced).

Comment: @psmears i tried (and i understood) what you mean but it doesnt make changes in the program

Comment: @soon: I think using iterators for their intended purpose (i.e. iterating over collections) is a good idea. People only need to use the proper syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "iterator not incrementable" message is a *runtime* error.  It is your implementation doing bounds-checking on the iterators , and it has detected that either:

```
it += notas / 10;
```

or the following `it++` causes `it` to go beyond `arcNotas.end()`.

You should fix your code to check the length before doing this addition, as well as fixing the problem where you increment the iterator instead of dereferencing first.

Comment: Thats right... changing the vector inicialization to (11,0) solved the main problem... it was a run time error. If the grade was 100 it was to the v[10], when my vector just have [9] (from zero). The second problem, the non increment to the it was solved using the notation *it=*it+1; what i dont undestand is why... i tried with *(it)++, (*it)++, ++*(it) but it just doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is one of operator precedence. In short, your line `*it++;` is wrong. This is the equivalent of writing `*(it++)`, which will provide the old value after evaluating `++` operator first, and then dereference that.

Instead, what you want to do is dereference `it` first and then increment the value by writing `(*it)++`. This is because the `++` operator has higher precedence than the indirection operator `*`.

I'll illustrate with a documented code example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> grades(5, 0);
    auto it = grades.begin();

    cout << "Show initial elements before increment..." << endl;
    while(it != grades.end()) {
        cout << *it << endl;

        // operator precedence is important;
        // ++ has higher precedence than * for indirection;
        // therefore the observable side-effects are that:
        (*it)++;    // ...this increments the current element pointed by 'it'
        *it++;      // ...this causes 'it' to point to the next element after the old value has been dereferenced w/o additional side-effect
    }

    cout << endl << "Show incremented elements..." << endl;
    it = grades.begin();
    while(it != grades.end()) {
        // notice that elements have been incremented only once by this point
        // not twice as the operator precedence mistake would lead you to believe
        cout << *it << endl;
        it++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The command to build this program (GNU/Linux) and its output are below:

```
➜  /tmp  g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp -o test
➜  /tmp  ./test
Show initial elements before increment...
0
0
0
0
0

Show incremented elements...
1
1
1
1
1
```

Notice that the values are only incremented once, not twice and you would probably have expected, given your current misunderstanding.

Comment: This ia bit misleading. Postfix imcrement operator returns the **old** value of its argument.

Comment: For completeness, you may want to specify that in `*it++`, it is the old value of `it` that is dereferenced, not the incremented one. Even if that makes little difference when the dereferenced value is not used.

Comment: @n.m.: I've updated the post. I don't think this necessarily warranted a down-vote. I thought it was clear from context I just talking about the observable side-effects of the instructions.